# How to add Java JAR files to Grails project?

Tags: java, grails, maven, jar, dependencies

I have a few Java/Maven projects that I want to use in a Grails 2.0.4 project. I have tried various approaches, such as:

1. Installing the JAR files in my local maven repository, and executing `grails install-dependency com.foo:my-project:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`
2. Copying the JAR files into the `lib` folder of grails.
3. Adding `compile com.foo:my-project:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` to the dependencies section of `BuildConfig.groovy`
4. Uncommenting `mavenLocal()` and passing `/home/me/.m2/repository`

I may have tried a few other things, such as superstitiously throwing in a `grails clean` whenever convenient. In every case `grails compile` yields the following result: compilation fails, unable to resolve every reference to any of the classes in either of the JARs.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: That's really weird because any of those options should work...  You didn't happen to compile the classes in your JAR with a newer version of Java than you're running Grails with did you?  I ran into a similar problem with a PostgreSQL driver jar one time and that was the cause.

Comment: Can you verify the jar file contains the missing classes with `jar tf lib.jar | grep mypackage.MyClass`?

Comment: I've been caught by something like this in the past... I had forgotten to `import` the classes I was using.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Putting the jar in the lib folder should do the trick. We are using the same approach currently without problems.

Comment: The default `lib` folder is gone as of Grails 3.0.  http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/single.html#upgrading --> "Dependency resolution should be used to resolve JAR files"

Answer (score 14):

If *Grails* by default don't take the local *.jar* libraries located in `<GRAILS-APP-DIR>/lib` (seems that with *Grails 3.X* the `/lib` folder default configuration is removed) the easy way to enforce it is modifying `build.gradle` to add a local directory dependency for it.

For almost all cases is of course better to use the *maven* repos, however it's possible to have some `db-vendor-drivers` or other libraries which aren't in a public repo. To do so for this libraries modify the `<GRAILS-APP-DIR>/build.gradle` and add something like:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile fileTree(dir: './lib', include: ['*.jar'])
    ...
}
```

If you want you can use another directory (not `/lib`) since you're specifying it. Of course use the correct scope (for example for `db-vendor-drivers` which probably already are in your application container class path the scope in gradle will be `runtime` instead of `compile`).

**UPDATE**

Starting from gradle 7.0 use of `compile` and `runtime` are removed. Insted you can use `compileOnly`, `runtimeOnly` or `implementation` depending if you want to put the dependency only in the complie classpath, runtime classpath or on both, in gradle 7.0 and above you can use :

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation fileTree(dir: './lib', include: ['*.jar'])
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you give such careful answers to ancient questions. I hope this helps someone, but I won't try to evaluate it. I haven't done any Grails in over three years.

Comment: @EricWilson I'm just trying `Grails` for first time..., I see that this question has only answers with the thing to do but not explanation about how it works. So I simply try to argue how it works. Don't worry I'm not looking that you check the answer `:)`, I only post it if it helps someone.

Answer (score 9):

Adding the jar to the "lib" folder wasn't enough for me. I had to run:

```
grails compile --refresh-dependencies
```

After what it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Grails refresh-dependency, clean etc. didn't work for me. What worked for me was exiting Grails daemon and starting Grails again.