# Adding External JAR's to Grails Application

Tags: grails, groovy, jar, atom-editor

I am attempting to run a grails application which requires the use of external JAR's in order to execute. However, I am not sure how to add my JAR's to the directory in order for any of my groovy files to recognize the classes defined in the JAR files.

If I were to load my grails application into an IDE, I know I would be able to add them into external libraries; unfortunately, I am only limited to using ATOM Text Editor.

Any suggestions?

Comment: which version of grails? is it some kind of private secret jar, or available through maven repo? maybe from private maven repo?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add Java JAR files to Grails project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215351/how-to-add-java-jar-files-to-grails-project)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Grails 3 you can add the JAR to your dependencies{} in build.gradle

Make sure the JAR is located in one of the repositories checked by gradle. For example, you can manually add the JAR to your local Maven repo, make sure mavenLocal() is added to your repositories{} in build.gradle.

By default, Maven local repository is default to .m2 folder :

1. Unix/Mac OS X – ~/.m2
2. Windows – C:\Documents and Settings{your-username}.m2